# Error with admin.autodiscover in production

Tags: python, django, django-urls, production, autodiscovery

Trying to run into production django-project. On the development everything works well. On the production I've got 500 error

Here is Stack trace:

```
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 164, in _add_installed_apps_translations
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 116, in __init__
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 206, in translation
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 304, in do_translate
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 327, in ugettext
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 84, in ugettext
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 141, in __text_cast
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 92, in force_text
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 37, in format
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 270, in r
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 37, in format
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 345, in format
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 774, in date
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 674, in resolve
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 89, in render
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 384, in get_traceback_html
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 97, in technical_500_response
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 261, in handle_uncaught_exception
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 67, in autodiscover_modules
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
File "/home/megatexp/megatex_new/djangosites/megatex_new/megatex_new/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in resolve
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 119, in get_response
```

And global urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from articles.views import ArticleView
from shop.views import HomeView
from feedback.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    url(r'^about/$', ArticleView.as_view(slug="Про нас"), name='about'),
    url(r'^feedback/', include('feedback.urls')),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

`DEBUG = True` in settings.

Also app is running not on the root of the domain. Maybe it cause some problems with autodiscover. Thus I also have added `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`, but the result is the same: `500 internal server error`.

I've tried to remove admin.autodiscover() from urls.py but I still got 500 error. 
Here is stack

```
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 164, in _add_installed_apps_translations
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 116, in __init__
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 206, in translation
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 304, in do_translate
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 327, in ugettext
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 84, in ugettext
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 141, in __text_cast
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 92, in force_text
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 37, in format
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 270, in r
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 37, in format
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 345, in format
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 774, in date
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 674, in resolve
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 89, in render
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 384, in get_traceback_html
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 97, in technical_500_response
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 261, in handle_uncaught_exception
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 231, in is_installed
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 171, in check_dependencies
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 250, in get_urls
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 291, in urls
File "/home/megatexp/megatex_new/djangosites/megatex_new/megatex_new/urls.py", line 27, in <module>
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in resolve
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 119, in get_response
```

It can not resolve admin.urls

Looks like misconfiguration on server, but what is the exact problem I can not determine. I ran this project on local apache with mod_wsgi and all is ok. When I tested it on production server I faced with this situation.

Comment: Where is the actual error?

Comment: File "/home/megatexp/megatex_new/djangosites/megatex_new/megatex_new/urls.py", line 25, in <module> - Here it is. The string admin.autodiscover() produces error

Comment: is this /home/megatexp/megatex_new/djangosites/megatex_new/megatex_new/urls.py your global urls.py file?

Comment: Which django version are you using? admin.autodiscover is depricated since 1.7

Comment: Ajey Gupta, yes it is.

Comment: I use Django 1.8.2 In development all is ok and there was no problems with that line

Comment: Without admin.autodiscover it can not resolve admin urls.

Comment: what is the error message?? (not traceback lines)

Comment: @doniyor I could not see error message itself, only error log on server. On the server i see default 500 error (not django's). File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 384, in get_traceback_html
File "/home/megatexp/virtualenv/megatex__new_djangosites/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 97, in technical_500_response. It seems that there is error in displaying 500 django error itself.

Comment: @ЖеняГрубіян can you turn ``debug=True``?